# React dom-to-image npm Module Ignores Border Image of Input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and I would like to take a snapshot of a particular div which contains some inputs, labels, images, so I have used the npm module [dom-to-image](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image) and its works fine, except for the border image of input. It ignores the border image of input.

How to make it work? Thanks in advance.

Link: https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image

code:

```
takeSnapshot(event){
    var image = this.refs["testPreview"];

    var testDiv = document.getElementById("test");

    domToImage.toPng(testDiv)
        .then(function (dataUrl) {
            image.src = dataUrl;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log('oops, something went wrong!');
        });
}
```

Comment: @Patrick Hund - did you find any solution for my problem?

Comment: Hello Ras, no, I just edited your question to make it easier for others to understand and to find an answer.

Comment: Hai patrick,Thank you for your help